# TV show about four boys who gain elemental powers and fight/kill demons that pose as their friends or random people

Tags: story-identification, tv

Okay, so there's a TV show I need to find that aired around 2012-2016 and had 2-3 seasons.

There are four boys who, later into the series, gain elemental powers. Each gets one element; fire, water, earth, air, with a special necklace that sorta looks like a pentagram. They fight/kill demons that pose either as their friends or random people. At one point, they get teleported to another dimension where they lose their powers.

And no, it's not *Avatar*, *Gormiti*, or *Ninjago*. Oh yeah, it aired in Canada and aired on like Teletoon, Disney Channel, or Disney XD, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: @DEMONIC_D - Hi, welcome to the site. I'm guessing this was animated, since you mentioned some animated shows, but can you confirm that?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Does Nowhere Boys, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Boys, ring a bell?

Answer (score 0):

As noted by jim in a comment, this looks like it's *[Nowhere Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Boys)*, which aired four seasons between 2013 and 2018 as well as a film in 2016, [*Nowhere Boys: the Book of Shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Boys:_The_Book_of_Shadows).

> After returning home from a school excursion, four boys, Felix Ferne, Andy Lau, Sam Conte, and Jake Riles find themselves in an alternate reality where no one recognises them. They battle mystical threats and demons to find their way back home.
>
> One week after the boys return home, they discover they have special elemental powers after returning from the alternate reality but when they thought they were at peace, they discover they weren't the only ones who crossed over from the alternate reality.
>
> When a new student, Luke, attends Bremin High, he encounters Ben, Heath, Nicco and Jesse who become suspicious of Ben who realises they have special powers and they use them to fight a creature known as the "Mega-Demon".

As noted on [the wiki](https://nowhere-boys.fandom.com/wiki/Nowhere_Boys), the original four boys wielded the powers of fire, water, air, and earth. They gained their powers courtesy of the [Talisman](https://nowhere-boys.fandom.com/wiki/Talisman).

### Show openings

Answer (score -2):

The show you are talking about is nowhere boys.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] your answer to add some details about this show and how it matches the details of the question?  You might want to read [answer].